# How to install discord.py-rewrite dependency on Heroku for Discord bot hosting?

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I'm trying to deploy my discord.py bot on Heroku using my GitHub master branch, but have been unable to do because of a git error: `Could not find a tag or branch 'rewrite', assuming commit`. What do I need to do to successfully install the 'rewrite' dependency?

I am currently using the files "requirements.txt", "runtime.txt", "Procfile" and "Aptfile". I've tried several combinations of dependencies in my requirements.txt file, including:

- git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite
- git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py
- discord.py
- dnspython==1.16.0
- PyNaCl==1.3.0

These are the contents of my files needed for Heroku:

requirements.txt: `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite`

runtime.txt: `python-3.6.8`

Procfile: `worker: python bot.py`

Aptfile: `git`

When using anything *but* `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite` in attempts to get the bot deployed, `heroku logs --tail` will display the error:

```
self.custom_red = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 0, 0)  # ff0000
AttributeError: type object 'Colour' has no attribute 'from_rgb'
```

The important thing I want to emphasize is that PyCharm *does not* throw this error locally, even having tested that part of the code. This is how I came to the conclusion that that I am having issues with installing the 'rewrite' dependency on Heroku.

This here is the full error log on Heroku:

```
-----> Uninstalling stale dependencies
       Uninstalling discord.py-0.16.12:
         Successfully uninstalled discord.py-0.16.12
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite (from -r /tmp/build_9642c6bfbfd8e0f0ea526230740f0bd1/requirements.txt (line 1))
         Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to rewrite) to /tmp/pip-41cdp1qz-build
         Could not find a tag or branch 'rewrite', assuming commit.
       error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git.
       Command "git checkout -q rewrite" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-41cdp1qz-build
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

That being said, are there any suggestions to help me get past this error by successfully installing the "rewrite" dependency and thus, have my bot functional on Heroku?

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite branch has been merged, and no longer exists.  Use the version of [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) available from PyPI, that's currently the latest.

Comment: Did not work. Heroku deployed it, but I still received the same AttributeError shown above. EDIT: If I understood what you meant by "use", I did: ```py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py```, and simply left requirements.txt with ```discord.py```. Tested and worked in PyCharm locally. Then I committed, pushed, deployed branch, and crashed with that error.

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work now. Just learned I had to specify ```discord.py==1.2.2```, not just ```discord.py``` in requirements.txt. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well try this
Put this into your requirement.txt

```
discord-ext-alternatives
discord
```

and it should ready to go